# How to handle the back event in nested NavHostFragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, dynamic-feature-module

I did take a look on the official website [Nested Graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) and searched related issues but have no luck on it.

When the nest graph and dynamic feature module comes up, I tried to combine **"dynamic feature module"**, **"Nested NavHostFragments"** and **"Nested Graph"** into a separate module. But when I tried to handle the back button event, I have no idea on it.

I have the NavHostFragments in the ***"app"*** module and when the user navigation the account item on the bottom navigation view. It will prompt up a bottomsheetdialog, which contains a nested NavHostFragment and also its navigation graph. And those fragments are inside ***"account"*** module.

When I tried to navigation back by pressing back button in the account page, it does not get back the stacks inside the nested NavHostFragment. This [`setPrimaryNavigationFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#setprimarynavigationfragment) function seems providing some clue for this issue but i have no luck on it.

That's the current behavior

[image: current_behavior]

MainActivity.kt (In "app" module)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    }
    private val listener =
        NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            model.triggerDestination(destinationId = destination.id)
        }

    private val model: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_explore
            )
        )

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        model.notificationPageSelect.observe(this, EventObserver {
            when (it) {
                R.id.navigation_explore -> updateAppBarBg(R.drawable.explore_appbar_bg_gradient)
                R.id.navigation_notifications -> updateAppBarBg(R.drawable.notification_appbar_bg_gradient)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun updateAppBarBg(appBg: Int) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundResource(appBg)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/explore_appbar_bg_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.fragment.DynamicNavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AccountListDialogFragment.kt (in "account" module)

```
class AccountListDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SettingsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setupFullExpand()
    }

}
```

fragment_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/account" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: The sample project did not use the nested NavHostFragments. Could you please explain why the link is related to my issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for a solution for multiple back stack, right? If so, then that sample is useful.

Comment: Ok. My issue is about the nested NavHostFragments and the back event. I will  take a look on it first. And thank you for the information. If it helps my issue, I will post the answer here. Otherwise, having the link without any explanation cannot help to solve the issue.

Comment: In theory, you should have only 1 NavHostFragment. If you have to have a bottom navigation view available that retains the state of the stack as you navigate between them regardless of depth, then you can use the *hack* that you have N top-level NavHostFragments. I do not see why you would ever nest NavHostFragments, but surely you can do some magic tricks by registering a `BackPressDispatcher` on the host activity.